# web3.py - How to get status from ERC20 approve?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, web3.py, erc-20-approve

I have a web3.py script that approves ERC20 tokens to maximum - Web3.toWei((2**256)-1,'wei')  - to bunch of different ER20 tokens (some have 18 decimals, some have 6) on Fantom chain.
When i try to bulk approve a bunch at the same time, the script sometimes works.. sometimes doesn't. What i mean by "doesn't"

- the script executes fine, but when I query ERC20's allowance() function, still shows zero
- I'd get this random error: "replacement transaction underpriced"
  Any ideas where Im going wrong?

Web3.py code:

```
token = w3.eth.contract(
    address=erc20_address, 
    abi=ERC20_ABI
)

tx = token.functions.approve(
    spender_address, 
    Web3.toWei((2**256)-1,'wei')
    ).buildTransaction({
    'from': wallet_address,
    'nonce': get_nonce(),
    "gasPrice": int(w3.eth.gas_price * 1), 
    "chainId": CHAIN_ID
})

signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, os.getenv("key"))
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
tx_hash_hex  = Web3.toHex(tx_hash)
```

if i look up tx_hash_hex on ftmscan, this shows nothing. This executes fine, so I would think that the erc20 token approval went through, but if I check via ftmscan, it shows approval amount as 0

1. where am i going wrong?
2. Is there a way to view the approval status / reason?

Comment: That error usually means you have created two transaction with the same nonce. Possible solutions are: 1/ enforce consecutive, non repeating nonces, 2/ wait for transaction confirmation between transactions.